# Using Views' Contextual filters in a Panel for one taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels, views

I have one taxonomy term, Country, which is linked to another, People. One people is from one country.

How can I make a view in my Panel, using Contextual filters, in order to show the specific view I prepared for "Country" ? I tried to use contextual filters to do so, and it works when I use the preview with the Country ID - but not in Panels.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're ACTUALLY asking - perhaps you could provide a little more information?

Comment: Are you sure you mean taxonomy **term** or do you mean **vocabulary** (collection of terms)?  Terms: US, Canada, Mexico / Vocabulary: Countries

Comment: Sorry if unclear, I just wanted to know how to display a view related to a taxonomy term link, while using a contextual filter for example.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I want to use **terms** and not vocabularies, my mistake while I typed ... If my people is from France, I want to show a view I created for France - is it clearer ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted to by taking the problem reversely :

- I created my view, then added a contextual filter not by "Country ID", as I did, but by "People ID"
- Then I configured the argument input in Views by taking the source from the argument of the panel (which matched my "People ID") and it was taken in account by my Views and actually works.

Drupal is quite complicated to understand sometimes ! :) Thanks for advice Patrick Kenny ;)

Bye

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a different view for a country, I think what you probably want to do is use the Taxonomy Term override page rather than using contextual filters.

To do this, go to the pages admin screen (/admin/structure/pages).  Then, enable the **Taxonomy term template** panel to override the display of taxonomy terms using Panels.

To show a custom view, you can edit the **Taxonomy term template** panel.  This will allow you to use the taxonomy term as arguments for your view, because Panels understands that you are overriding the taxonomy term display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I admit my question is not very well asked ...

In fact, I need to have 2 blocks, with one for the "People" and one from the "country"

Like 

Block 1 :
France
Capital: Paris
[Photo]
President: blabla

Block 2 : 
Name: aaaa
Surname: bbb
Address: ccc
Country: France

Am I clearer ?

Comment: In that case, you can add two different views to the taxonomy term override page.  View 1 shows the country information (capital, photo, etc.)  View 2 shows the people in that country.  You can just create both views and add them to the "content" of the panel.

Comment: But how do I get the country ID from one view to pass it as a contextual filter parameter in my second view ?

Comment: If you are using Panels, and you are overriding the taxonomy term display, use a *Content Pane* display (in Views, instead of a block display) and enable "use panel argument" (you will have to set the appropriate context).  This will allow you to populate your contextual filter with the country ID being passed to panels.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do - but how can I pass the country ID to the other panel ? Since I only have the country name displayed in my term view ?

Comment: You use one *panel*, the term override panel.  Then you attach multiple panes (made with Views).

Comment: Sorry I mistyped pane and panel ! I have one term override PANEL with two PANES actually (think it's time to change their taxonomy lol)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10256/discussion-between-marcandria-and-patrick-kenny)